# PHP Error 500 FastCGI process exceeded timeout errors intermittently on SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, pdo, iis-8

I'm intermittently getting an HTTP 500 FastCGI process error only on a particular SQL Server Stored procedure. The rest of PHP server and queries are still running. I have 3 PHP servers connecting to 1 SQL server database server. The error is happening on all PHP servers simultaneously. I can make the error go away by recompiling the stored procedure in SQL Management Studio.

Why does recompiling the stored procedure temporarily resolve the issue? Can I reset the database connection in PHP? Is there a particular connection string I should be using?

Using PDO sqlsrv 5.6.1

Comment: What is the error you are seeing in the error logs? What's the cause for this issue?

Comment: I see a 500 error in IIS, but no corresponding error in php logs.

Comment: 500 error means that the server had an error processing your request. If you can't find the error logged anywhere (IIS or PHP logs) then maybe you have error logging switched off?